# AngularJS custom directive binding to model

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build an object like: 
`{"age":"21","name":"foo", "address":["address1", "address2"]}`

For address I am using a custom directive, I don't know how to attach this to scope (person.address). If I give ng-model="person.address" in directive, it is taking same address for both the input texts. I have to isolate scope, but don't know where to put it.

Fiddle: http://codepen.io/goutham2027/pen/EagPZG

HTML

```
   <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
     <form>
       Name: <input type="text", ng-model="person.name"> <br/>
       Age:  <input type="text", ng-model="person.age"> <br/>
       Address-1 <address> </address>
       Alternate-Address <address>  </address>
     </form>
     {{person}}
      </div>
```

JS

```
app.directive('address', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text">'
  }
})
```

Edit: I found out how to do it. 
Fiddle: http://codepen.io/goutham2027/pen/LEjaXP

Comment: An isolated scope can help http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYKeXv

Answer (score 1):

Just add an isolated scope to your directive:

```
app.directive('address', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="ngModel" type="text">'
  }
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raMxJo

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `person` attribute to your controller.

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.person = {age:"21",name:"foo", address:["address1", "address2"]};
});
```

As for using your custom directive to handle the two different address fields, go with the answer from @Rasalom.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the directive a private scope, like so:

```
scope: {
  model: '='
}
```

Then you'll be able to pass it to your directive:

`<address model="address"></address>`

In your directive the address is now available in the HTML template through the private scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isolated scope for that:

```
app.directive('address', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope : {person:'='},
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="person">'
  }
});

<div ng-controller="ctrl">
   <form>
     Name: <input type="text", ng-model="person.name">
     Age: <input type="text", ng-model="person.age"> <br/>
     Address-1: <address person="person.address1"> </address>
     Alternate-Address: <address person="person.address2"></address>
   </form>
</div>
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPRMZm)** example.

Comment: i want address in array.